# How to add condition into Regex?

Tags: python, regex

I've been searching everywhere but I haven't found any solution yet...
So for example, I have a list of names in my dataframe such as: Penelope Deans, Corinne M. Percell, Sally Seaborn, Tereasa T. Aranda and so on.
My current Regex is

`^[A-Z][a-z]+,?\s+(?:[A-Z][a-z]*\.?\s*)?[A-Z][a-z]+`

that catches most of the name. However, in the dataframe I also have rows like "Licensed Real Estate at XXX, Digital Marketer at YYY". And the above Regex also catches "Licensed Real Estate" and "Digital Marketer". I want to only select rows with just names, and how should I do? Can I somehow write regex to not catch any words that including the word"at"?

+++

So I'm working on dataframe of just one column and many rows,
the dataframe looks like this:

```
lst = [Penelope Deans, 1/1/2020, Digital Marketer at XXX, Corinne M. Percell, 1/1/2020, Tereasa T., Licensed Real Estate at YYY]

df = pd.DataFrame(lst)

df

    Info 
0  Penelope Deans 
1  1/1/2020 
2  Digital Marketer at XXX 
3  Corinne M. Percell 
4  1/1/2020 
5  Tereasa T. 
6  Licensed Real Estate at YYY

name_pat = r"^[A-Z][a-z]+,?\s+(?:[A-Z][a-z]*\.?\s*)?[A-Z][a-z]+"
df['Info'].str.findall(name_pat)
```

The output is

```
    Info 
0  Penelope Deans 
1  []
2  Digital Marketer
3  Corinne M. Percell 
4  [] 
5  Tereasa T. 
6  Licensed Real Estate
```

And I'm expecting as:

```
    Info 
0  Penelope Deans 
1  []
2  []
3  Corinne M. Percell 
4  []
5  Tereasa T. 
6  []
```

Comment: I see the problem. Based on your follow up, without further information, I'd say it's impossible to distinguish a comma-delimited list of names that also contains commas with titles or other information. [This article explains why](https://www.kalzumeus.com/2010/06/17/falsehoods-programmers-believe-about-names/). The task you're essentially asking for seems to be "how do I identify `'Tereasa T.'` as a name and `'Licensed Real Estate'` as a non-name?".

Comment: @ggorlen Yes, So for example, Licensed Real Estate row is actually Licensed Real Estate at XXX. And the regex is extracting Licensed Real Estate from the row. So I wanted to know if I can add a condition to Regex, for example (if there is "at" then no match).

Comment: OK, I see. Can you show a relevant snippet of the actual data you're working with? The exact format is still unclear, which is important for writing regexes. You can hardcode in this logic quite easily, but your application will fail if a user with an unusual name like `"Jeremy at Thompson" arrives. [Also relevant](https://www.wired.com/2015/11/null/).

Comment: Your first problem is to decide what exactly qualifies as a person's name (and deciding that anything else does not). Is `'Jill van den Burg'` a valid name? `'Jean de Paris'`? `'Maurice l'Oreal'`? `'Jack Daniels'`? `'Walt Disney'`? `'Walt Disney Inc.'`? `'Walt Disney Esq.'`?

Comment: @ggorlen I just added! Can you please take a look at it? Thank you

Comment: @Grismar So when I run the regex, I get all the name and PLUS job title name, as they have a similar structure.

Comment: @ggorlen I have edited again, sorry for the inconvenience.

Comment: You could paste this to the end of that too-inclusive regex: `\b(?! \u)(?! at)`. It (1) forces the last word to properly end, (2) prohibits a next uppercase-starting name, and (3) specifically prevent a next `at`. (Is uppercase `\u` in Python? If not, use `[A-Z]`.)

Comment: Yeah, I realized than after posting and so added an edit. Sorry.

Comment: @usr2564301 Omg! It works great on Regex tester, but when I do it on Jupyter notebook I get an error of "incomplete escape \u at position 56". It seems like it's different python issues. But thank you sooo much!

Comment: So don't use `\u`. I included a valid alternative.

Comment: @usr2564301 Oops Thank you sooooo much I got too excited.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The key thing is to decide what decides a value is a name and what isn't.

From your examples, it appears that `'Penelope Deans'`, `'Corinne M. Percell'` and `'Tereasa T.'` are names, while `'1/1/2020'` isn't (because it has numbers and slashes) and `'Digital Marketer at XXX'` isn't either because it follows the pattern `<namelike> at <namelike>`.

Note that under those rules `'John at Smith'` wouldn't be a name either. But since 'at' is not a normal nobiliary particle in English, it should work and you're not looking to cover foreign names specifically (and even then, 'at' is rare in a name).

A solution in Python using regex:

```
import pandas as pd

lst = [
    'Penelope Deans', '1/1/2020', 'Digital Marketer at XXX', 'Corinne M. Percell', 
    '1/1/2020', 'Tereasa T.', 'Licensed Real Estate at YYY'
]

df = pd.DataFrame(lst)

df = df[df[0].str.match('^((?! at )[A-z\s\.])+$')]

print(df)
```

Result:

```
                    0
0      Penelope Deans
3  Corinne M. Percell
5          Tereasa T.
```